# Does ASP.NET Identity inherently support Denial Of Service (DOS) mitigation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a authorisation project utilising [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity).

It appears to offer the majority of features one would expect to see, and indeed most of what we require.

One feature I wish to support is to mitigate the risk of a brute force attack.  I understand there is an **Account Lockout** feature which will help stop an attack against a given username.  However this will not mitigate against a username enumeration attack (i.e. trying a given password against different accounts).

I can't find anything in the documentation and was wondering if anyone else knew better.  Or would I have to [implement something myself](http://madskristensen.net/post/block-dos-attacks-easily-in-aspnet). Or use IIS.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing built-in but you can do locking (with timeout) using IP address. See for example [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471907/block-user-ip-after-5-unsuccessful-login-attempts) but on the net there are better resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [MvcThrottle](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcThrottle/) package, it lets you define rate limits based on IP and URL.

In your case you could throttle the Login action like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        var throttleFilter = new ThrottlingFilter
        {
            Policy = new ThrottlePolicy(perSecond: 10)
            {
                IpThrottling = true,
                EndpointThrottling = true
            },
            Repository = new CacheRepository()
        };

        filters.Add(throttleFilter);
    }
}
```

Attribute based rate limiting:

```
[EnableThrottling(PerSecond = 2)]
public ActionResult Login()
{
  ...
}
```

For more configurations details check out the [setup tutorial](https://github.com/stefanprodan/MvcThrottle).

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  Looks promising, I'll take a look.

Comment: For anyone else reading, Stefan also produces a version for the ASP.NET Web API (which I'm using, and failed to mention in the question!)  ---  https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle